# Hard to get the propositional resolution

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am given a premise and its resolution. But I cannot understand the steps. The premise is:

```
~(p|q => q|s)
```

and when I put that to http://intrologic.stanford.edu/applications/converter.html I get the result below:

```
{p,q}, {~q}, {~s}
```

I tried to get the same result by my hand but failed. So far I reached:

```
~(p | q => q | s)
(p & ~q & ~s) | (r & ~q & ~s)
(p|r) & (p|~q) & (p|~s) & ~q & ~s
```

But I stucked here. How can I get the final answer from here?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What does $|$ mean in $p|q$ ? [I assume not "p divides q...]

Comment: @coffeemath | is a disjunction.

Comment: @coffeemath  For ease of keyboard entry, Stanford's logic applications use "|" for "or", "&" for "and", "~" for "not", and of course, "=>" for "implies".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace (a => b) with (~a | b):

~(p|q => q|s)

~(~(p|q) | (q|s))

(p|q) & (~(q|s))

(p|q) & (~q) & (~s)

Comment: Also note that for this expression to be true, q and s must be false. Because q is false, the value of p|q is actually equalt to p. So this expressoin can be true only for p=true, q=s=false.

Comment: I see! I should've stopped at (p|q) & (~q) & (~s) but I went on further and found myself in the endless maze such as (p & ~q & ~s) | (r & ~q & ~s). Thank you for the insight!